# Can't find frames children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame, frameset

I'm maintaining an old site that uses frameset/frames.

I wan't to attach a handler to the main frame so when the user clicks the body somewhere an alert will pop up.

I've been banging my head for a while now, but I now feel like I'm so close I can taste it, yet I still can't figure out the problem. I'm using jquery 1.5.1.

```
$(function () {
    $($('frame[name="main"]')).ready(function () {
        console.log($('frame[name="main"]')); // this is a success (I can view it in firebug
        console.log($('frame[name="main"]').find('body')); // fails (nothing is found)
    });
});
```

Here are the frames

```
<frameset cols="190,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" framepadding="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <frame name="head" src="someHTMLPage1.html" scrolling="no" noresize frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" framepadding="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <frame name="main" src="someHTMLPage2.html" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" framepadding="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Arturo,

Your solution helped but wasn't perfect. Here's what I did.

```
$(function () {

    $($('frame[name="info"]')).load(function () {
        var doc = window.frames["info"].document;
        doc.onclick = function () { alert('something') };
    });
});
```

I had to use `.load` instead of `.ready` in order for this to work.

This worked in IE 7/8/8-compatibility-mode and FF4 and Chrome 12 (probably works in earlier versions of FF and Chrome, I just didn't test)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, jquery ready doesn't work very well with window it was designed for document. A frame encapsulates a window.

Also i think you need to load jquery on the page inside your frame to find the body.
Try without jQuery

```
var doc = window.frames["main"].document;
var bdy = doc.body;
bdy.onclick = function() { alert("your text here") };
```

The other thing that can also affect you is if your page in the frame is not in the same domain as the frameset. This would block any script from the frameset.

Also you can change to load instead of ready

`$($('frame[name="main"]')).load(function() { ...`

Comment: The problem with adding it to the page inside the frame is that this page is swapped constantly with LOTS of other pages. I wanted to avoid having handlers on every single page if possible.

Comment: Are all those pages in the same domain of the frameset?

Comment: The other problem you might have is that when you are executing this block the document has not been loaded. Why don't you try `$($('frame[name="main"]')).load(function() ...` instead of ready

Comment: that's exactly what I had to do. Thanks mate :)